# Exception monad categorically

Tags: category-theory, monads

I have just started to `play around' with monads and I have a question on the *exceptions* monad (hopefully if I understand this, it will help me with other monads too). I seem to always find examples of monads only in Haskell, but I am more interested about the categorical definition of the monad (I am not familiar with Haskell notation).

Let $(T,\eta,\mu)$ be a monad on a given category, say $\mathsf{Sets}$. The exception monad is defined as $TX = X + E$. Now I was trying to define what $\eta$ and $\mu$ are for this monad. I am having some difficulties with $\mu$.

I think I should write: $\eta_X(x) = i_1(x)$ with $i_1$ the first coprojection. For $\mu$ I think I should be able to write something like:

$$\mu_X([[x,e_1],e_2]) = \begin{cases} 
 i_1 x ???\\
 i_2 ????
\end{cases}
$$
but I am stuck. It feels like one should take multiple coprojections ... anyway, I feel I am completely offtrack here. If anyone has a suggestion/reference, that would be wonderful!!

Comment: You say "let $T$ be a monad" like it can be any one, but then you seem to define a specific $T$. Also, what are $E$ and the operation $+$ ?

Comment: Note that the coproduct ($+$) of sets is the *disjoint union*, but your notation $[x,e]$ rather suggest to take an element from the *product* of the sets. To take an element from a coproduct; $a:X+E$ then either $a:X$ or $a:E$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll assume $\eta$ is the identity and $\mu$ is the multiplication. Not sure what your brackets are. I'll assume $+$ denotes coproduct. (A little odd, given that you aren't familiar with Haskell, since this is more of a type theory notation, rather than a categorical one)

Anyway. Let $C$ be a category. Let $E\in C$ be an object. 
Let $T:C\to C$ be defined by $X\mapsto X\amalg E$, $Tf = f\amalg 1_E$.

Let $\iota_X:X\to X\amalg E$, $\iota_E : E\to X\amalg E$ be the natural maps defining the coproduct.

Then $\eta_X:X\to X\amalg E$ is just the map $\iota_X$, and $\mu_X : X\amalg E \amalg E \to X\amalg E$ is defined by applying the universal property of the triple coproduct to the maps $\iota_X$, $\iota_E$, $\iota_E$.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I should have used $\amalg$: I have been seeing so much Haskell, that I started to get biased by their notation.  Thx!

Comment: $+$ is pretty common in category theory too. And, of course, there's more than a minor relationship between type theory and category theory.

Comment: @DerekElkins I imagine it's also used in category theory, particularly given the relationship between type theory and category theory. I just associate the notation much more with the type theory perspective, that's all.